# How to refresh or reload rc.conf in ranger file manager?

Tags: ranger

At the moment I am constantly changing the `rc.conf` and `rifle.conf` files, but every time I want to test the new configuration I need to exit ranger and start again.

Is there a solution for this?

In vim I use `:source ~/.vimrc` to reload the configuration file, but this doesn't work in ranger.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a tricky way to do this, and this may not always work if they change their code (and there could be cases where restarting `ranger` is better/safer).

### rc.conf

In `ranger`, assuming you have a custom `rc.conf` in `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`, type:

```
:eval fm.source(fm.confpath('rc.conf'))
```

I tested this by changing `set draw_borders true/false` in `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`.

### rifle.conf

In `ranger`, assuming you have a custom `rifle.conf` in `~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf`, type:

```
:eval fm.rifle.reload_config()
```

Note that this was tested with the latest Git commits.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Keybindings#quick-editing-rcconf says that you can use this to quickly edit the `rc.conf` file and source it once saving it:

```
map xx chain shell vim -p ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf; source ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf
```

and this works for `scope.sh`:

```
map xr chain shell vim -p ~/.config/ranger/scope.sh; source ~/.config/ranger/scope.sh
```

this is works for `rifle.conf`

```
map xr chain shell vim ~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf; eval fm.rifle.reload_config()
```

I'll update this reply once I know the correct configuration for `commands.py`. If anyone knows, please edit this.

Comment: [This part](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/fb1ba4a111f818cf2a7d6e9c2f6be230f60bcf69/ranger/core/main.py#L396) of ranger's source code loads `commands.py`. I wasn't able to call those functions from `rifle.conf`, though.